# Unity is broken after restart

Tags: unity, 15.04

After Ubuntu restart I have these problems:

1. Titles of windows are missing
2. System menu not displaying
3. Shortcuts Alt+F2 and Alt+Tab are not working. And into Gnome environment also.
4. Strange black border around context menu

May be after system updating 2015/05/11 Unity is broken.
I've re installed Unity, but still facing the same problems.

Ubuntu version - 15.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using CompizConfig Settings Manager. I set Ubuntu Unity Plugin on CompizConfig - windows headers, system menu - all components are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and finally was able to use alt+ctrl+del and selected gnome-session and clicked on end and then ok. This got me to login screen and I selected gnome flashback (metacity). All is good now.